# codeigniter URL change

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating eCommerce in Codeigniter. Here is the controller file for registration:

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {   
        
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('register');
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
        
        

    }

    public function home(){
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('common/slider');
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
    
    public function signup(){
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");
        $email = $this->input->post("email");
        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','User Name','required|is_unique[user.name]|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email address','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); 

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
                $this->load->model('register_model');
                
                if($this->register_model->register_user($username,$password,$email)){
                    $this->home();

                }else{
                    $this->index();
                }
        }else{
                $this->index();
        }
    }
    
}
```

On form submit the page is redirecting to the home page but the URL on the browser is (http://localhost:8080/codignitor_projects/shophere/register/signup) But I want to change the URL to this (http://localhost:8080/codignitor_projects/shophere/)

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. I don't know your CI version. I hope you are using the latest one and I am also giving my answer according to the latest version CI-4.

Please Write

```
return redirect()->to('index');
```

or

```
return $this->response->redirect(base_url('YourControllerName/index'));
```

instead of

```
$this->index();
```

To clearify this problem I would like to give you an example. Let, I have a `Test` controller and there are two functions such as `abc()` and `def()`

```
class Test extends Controller
{
    function abc()
    {
        echo "Hi ! I am ABC";
    }

    function def()
    {
        $this->abc();//URL will be: http://localhost/your_project_name/public/test/def
        //return redirect()->to('abc'); //URL will be: http://localhost/your_project_name/public/test/abc
        //return $this->response->redirect(base_url('Test/abc')); //URL will be:http://localhost/your_project_name/public/Test/abc

    }
}
```

There are three lines inside the `def()` function that give you the same result but the URL from first one to others will be different which is commented.